# disable update while collapse and expand treegrid extjs 4

Tags: extjs4

I have treegrid extjs 4.. I use proxy read, create, update and delete
but the problem is the treegrid always send update when I click collapse and expand in treegrid..
when I delete update proxy, I got collapsing failed..

anybody have idea to disable updating while collapsing and expanding??

this is my short code

```
Ext.define('storeLapObjTP', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',    
//storePlanningTP = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    pageSize:50,
    autoSync: true,
    model: 'mod_planningTP',
    method: 'POST',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: base_url+'project/getcomplete',
            create: base_url+'project/edit/'+'create',
            update: base_url+'project/edit/'+'update',
            destroy: base_url+'project/edit/'+'delete'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
        }
    },
    sorters: [{
        property: 'id',
        direction: 'desc'
    }],
});


Ext.define('gridTPcl', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    id:'gridLapTP',
    store: storeLapTP = new storeLapObjTP,
    collapsible: false,
    loadMask: true,
    region: 'center',
    margins: '0 0 0 0',
    autoScroll: false,
    useArrows: true,
    rootVisible: true,
    multiSelect: false,
    singleExpand: false,
    columns: 
        [
        {
            menuDisabled: true,
            sortable: false,
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            width: 20,
            items: [
        {
            xtype: 'treecolumn',
            header: 'Project Name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            width: 300,
            align: 'left',
        },
        {
            header: 'Id',
            dataIndex: 'id',
            hidden:true
        },{
            text:'Anggaran (Rp.000)',
            columns : [
                {
                    header: 'Budget',
                    dataIndex: 'budget',
                    width:80,
                    align: 'center',
                }, {
                    header: 'Total',
                    dataIndex: 'total',
                    width:80,
                    align: 'center',
                }
            ]
        }],
    selModel: {
        selType: 'rowmodel'
    },
    title: 'Project Tree',
    frame: false,
    tbar: new Ext.Toolbar({
        id: 'tbarlaptp',
        items: [
        comboYearLapTP,'-',comboYearLapTP,'-',{
            id : 'reloadbuttonlaptp',
            text: 'Reload',
            iconCls: 'reloadButton',
            disabled: true,
            tooltip: 'Reload Data and Ignore Change',
            handler : function(){
                this.up().up().store.load();
            }
        }]
    })
    ,
    plugins: [],
});
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour (my tree doesn't send update after expand/collapse). Which version of ExtJS do you use? Can you also send  a model source?

Comment: Ext.define('mod_planningTP', {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
       fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'id_company', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'company_name', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'budget_prosen', type: 'number' },
            { name: 'budget', type: 'number' },
            { name: 'expanded'  , type: 'boolean', defaultValue: true},
            { name: 'iconCls'  , type: 'string', defaultValue: 'x-tree-noicon'},
        ]
    });